# My phonegap project's CSS works on my computer but not on my phone

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I've been working on an app for a bit now and finally tried it on a real phone (I'm using phonegap). It appears fine on my computer but the CSS doesn't work when I put it on my phone.

Desktop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s85qk.png

Phone (Androind 5.0 on Galaxy S5): https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIfzO.png

The code for linking the CSS is shown below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I just changed it a bit and put the CSS code directly onto the HTML file and it worked... So i'm assuming it has something to do with the linking.

Comment: Where does your css exist in your project?  Cordova/ phonegap copies over the www/ folder to the platform, so ensure the file/folder is in there.

Comment: It sits in the www folder.

Comment: This could be a lot of different things.  Since you are on Android 5.0, you should be able to use Chrome dev tools.  See this link: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging Can you post any information that pops up in the console there?